# PostgreSQL Slow DISTINCT WHERE

Tags: postgresql, distinct, where-clause

Imagine the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE drops(
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    loc VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    tag INT NOT NULL
);
```

What I want to do is perform a query where I can find all unique locations where a value matches the tag.

```
SELECT DISTINCT loc
FROM drops
WHERE tag = '1'
GROUP BY loc;
```

I am not sure whether it is due to the size (its 9m rows big!) or me being inefficient, but the query takes way too long for users to efficiently use it. At the time I was writing this, the above query took me 1:14 minutes.

Is there any tricks or methods I can utilize in order to shorten this to a mere few seconds?

Much appreciated!

The execution plan:

```
"Unique  (cost=1967352.72..1967407.22 rows=41 width=4) (actual time=40890.768..40894.984 rows=30 loops=1)"
"  ->  Group  (cost=1967352.72..1967407.12 rows=41 width=4) (actual time=40890.767..40894.972 rows=30 loops=1)"
"        Group Key: loc"
"        ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1967352.72..1967406.92 rows=82 width=4) (actual time=40890.765..40895.031 rows=88 loops=1)"
"              Workers Planned: 2"
"              Workers Launched: 2"
"              ->  Group  (cost=1966352.70..1966397.43 rows=41 width=4) (actual time=40879.910..40883.362 rows=29 loops=3)"
"                    Group Key: loc"
"                    ->  Sort  (cost=1966352.70..1966375.06 rows=8946 width=4) (actual time=40879.907..40881.154 rows=19129 loops=3)"
"                          Sort Key: loc"
"                          Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1660kB"
"                          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on drops  (cost=0.00..1965765.53 rows=8946 width=4) (actual time=1.341..40858.553 rows=19129 loops=3)"
"                                Filter: (tag = 1)"
"                                Rows Removed by Filter: 3113338"
"Planning time: 0.146 ms"
"Execution time: 40895.280 ms"
```

The table is indexed on `loc` and `tag`.

Comment: Do you have an index? Can you post the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` plan?

Comment: `GROUP BY` is superfluous with `DISTINCT` in your case. Keep only one among those in your query.

Comment: @KaushikNayak
I actually omitted `GROUP BY` as well initially, but surprisingly, it had an even worse performance, taking 2:44 minutes when I tried. The use of `GROUP BY` has shown an increase in speed in my case, but is there a specific reason why I should avoid doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 40 seconds are spent sequentially reading the whole table, throwing away 3113338 rows to keep only 19129.

The remedy is simple:

```
CREATE INDEX ON drops(tag);
```

But you say you have already done that, but I find it hard to believe. What is the command you used?

Change the condition in the query from

```
WHERE tag = '1'
```

to

```
WHERE tag = 1
```

It happens to work because `'1'` is a literal, but don't try to compare strings and numbers.

And, as has been mentioned, keep either the `DISTINCT` or the `GROUP BY`, but not both.

Comment: I actually went back and double checked it again and as it turns out, the indexes were indeed gone! When we tried to rebuild the index, it turns out that it had failed due to duplicate values appearing in a primary key column for some reason.

After we got rid of all the duplicates and rebuild the indexes, the query time has been reduced to a mere 1.6 seconds. The issue is as good as resolved, so thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you have used a `GROUP BY` clause, then there is no need to use the `DISTINCT` keyword. Omitting that should speed up the running time for the query.